# Android App crashing while trying to login

Tags: android, web-services

Hi I am a newbie to android world. I am trying to create a login page for my app that will take the user id and password through editext and post it in the url for login authentication. I have written the following code(source internet) but my application is crashing. I also wanted to check whether the authentication was successful  or not, but i am not able to go further as my app is crashing. Could someone please help me out. Below is the code for my app. 
Thanks.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;   
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class Login extends Activity {

    Button ok,back,exit;
    TextView result;
    String tag= "abc";

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

        public void postLoginData(String username, String password ) {
            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();


            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("(my url)");

            try {
                // Add user name and password


                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                Log.i(tag, "name and password");
                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                Log.w(tag, "Execute HTTP Post Request");
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                String str = InputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
            }
}


private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        // Read response until the end
        try {
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
            total.append(line); 
        }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Return full string
        return total;
        }


LOGCAT:

01-02 09:13:14.802: W/dalvikvm(2933): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
01-02 09:13:14.951: E/AndroidRuntime(2933): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 09:13:14.951: E/AndroidRuntime(2933): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
01-02 09:13:14.951: E/AndroidRuntime(2933):     at com.example.project1.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:40)
01-02 09:13:14.951: E/AndroidRuntime(2933):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
01-02 09:13:14.951: E/AndroidRuntime(2933):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
01-02 09:13:14.951: E/AndroidRuntime(2933):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-02 09:13:14.951: E/AndroidRuntime(2933):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-02 09:13:14.951: E/AndroidRuntime(2933):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-02 09:13:14.951: E/AndroidRuntime(2933):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-02 09:13:14.951: E/AndroidRuntime(2933):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 09:13:14.951: E/AndroidRuntime(2933):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-02 09:13:14.951: E/AndroidRuntime(2933):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-02 09:13:14.951: E/AndroidRuntime(2933):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-02 09:13:14.951: E/AndroidRuntime(2933):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-02 09:13:15.191: W/ActivityManager(278):   Force finishing activity com.example.project1/.MainActivity


This is MainActivity:

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public  class MainActivity extends Activity  {

Button ok,back,exit;

String tag= "Project 1";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();                 
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);             
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Login button clicked
        ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b);
        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                EditText uname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.id);
                String username = uname.getText().toString();

                EditText pword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.psswd);
                String password = pword.getText().toString();
                Login l = new Login();
                l.postLoginData(username, password);


            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: you can solve it yourself by  logcat "ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditTexT"

Comment: I have checked but am not getting anywhere.

Comment: what is line number 40 in MainActivity.java ?

Comment: I just create the test project with your code and strangely, the error i got was `IllegalArgumentException` which because of URL. Can you confirm your error, @user1917634 ?

Answer (score 0):

Your exception says everything.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
```

What you have in the xml layout is `TextView`,instead of `EditText`.

Comment: <EditText
        android:id="@+id/psswd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/b"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>
EditText
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/psswd"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/psswd"
        android:ems="10" />

Comment: @user1917634 : just refresh and Clean your current project then try to run

Answer (score 0):

Need to see your layout XML to be sure, but here, you are casting to EditText. I bet your layout XML declares either or both of id and psswd as TextView:

```
EditText uname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.id);
String username = uname.getText().toString();

EditText pword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.psswd);
String password = pword.getText().toString();
```

Comment: I have checked everything in my xml, psswd and id are edittext.

Comment: @user1917634 : where is EditText with id `@+id/id` ?

Comment: Then may be its picking the wrong/old xml layout. Try to clean the project and re-run it.